# Divide data into three columns in while loop

Tags: php, html

On my website I'm using a three column layout to display some cards - a bit like Google+. However, the cards I'm displaying are dynamic as in I don't know how many will be displayed. I don't know how I can divide these over the three columns evenly.

This is a typical column:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>A Title here.</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle pull-right"> <a href="#">A description here.</a></p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr>
            Some text here.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>A Title here.</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle pull-right"> <a href="#">A Description here.</a></p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr>
            Some text here.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the PHP loop I use - it's fairly standard: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { }`

There are three of these and ideally I want the cards to be evenly distributed over the three columns.

Comment: 3 of what ? please paste your code .

Comment: There are 3 `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">` next to each other. And I want to distribute the `<div class="panel panel-default">` over these.

Answer (score 2):

This is the example pattern for printing every three records in one row:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
$column = 3;
while(...){
  if($i % $column == 0){
   //1- print start tag of wrapper
  }
  //2- print columns
  $i++;
  if($i % $column == 0){
   //3- print end tag of wrapper
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, this is over three rows. What I want is three columns.

Comment: He's right it is 3 columns inside one row, but it puts the first 3 cards in the first column then closes it so there will ever only be 3 in there.

The best way would be to drop first card in the first column, then the second in the second column, then the third in the third column, THEN go back to the first column and put the forth card in there too etc. But I'm not sure how to achieve this.